# Would questions about C "translations" be on topic?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, asking-questions

I come from C programming, and as clear as they may be, I do not understand many of the examples in the documentation.

Would it be on topic to ask for a C "translation" of some examples?

Comment: I frankly think it's not necessarily so much about if it's appropriate, but rather that often there is no practical way to translate examples to C...

Comment: Can you give two or three examples of questions that you would have?

Comment: @CarlLange for example the example for `Reap` and `Sow` https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html

Comment: And you would be asking "What is the C equivalent of the Reap and Sow functionality?"

Comment: @CarlLange yes.

Comment: I personally think it would be on topic, since we do get [questions like that about Matlab](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=matlab). However, I don't think you'd be broadly successful in getting answers. Perhaps better to ask specific questions about things you don't understand asking for further explanation (with your C experience in mind), rather than questions that ask for equivalent functionality in a different language. Answerers may not be C programmers and you might alienate them by asking for C translations when what you might really need is a different explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Posting my comment as an answer, but don't take my opinion as fact:

I personally think it would be on topic, <s>since we do get [questions like that about Matlab](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=in+matlab)</s> (edit: turns out, we do not get exactly this type of question, but we do get IMO similar questions).  However, I don't think you'd be broadly successful in getting answers.

Perhaps better to ask specific questions about things you don't understand asking for further explanation (with your C experience in mind), rather than questions that ask for equivalent functionality in a different language.

Answerers may not be C programmers and you might alienate them by asking for C translations when what you might really need is a different explanation.

Comment: Can you narrow your query to examples of questions where OP gives WL code and the answer is a Matlab code? Because that is the case here.

Comment: Fair enough, that's a good point - usually the questions are more like "How can I do this like I do it in Matlab". I suppose this is what I mean in the third and fourth paragraph of my answer, by asking for a different explanation with the user's C experience in mind than asking for explicit C code.

Comment: I agree with the second part (+1) but not with the first part (-1) :)